# Spring boot @RequestParam String filter to JPA Specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring boot project with Jpa entities and rest controllers. I need to add server side search filter to those controllers.

From the UI side I receive a filter String as request parameter.

Example de the request parameter :
`[[["OrderDate","<","2018-07-24T00:00:00"],"or",["OrderDate",">=","2018-07-25T00:00:00"]],"and",["ShipCountry","contains","France"]]`

After some searching I tought about looking into regular expressions and try to use  JPASpecifications. But I don't know if it's the best way. Can anybody advise me ?

Thanks

Comment: how many special keys you can get? keys like `<`, `>`, `or`, `and`, `contains`...

Comment: For operators : `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `contains`, `notcontains`, `startswith`, `endswith`. For Operations login : `and`, `or`.

Comment: Yes. JPA Specification is the best way for advanced search or filter Rest API. That is JPA Criteria based solution . It can easily customize your request parameters and  allows you to filter down to exactly the resources you need.